# How to create a dijit/Dialog for a specific HTML Div and use Div's elements as its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, dialog

Learning from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Dialog.html, I know how to create dijit/Dialog widget programmatically and dynamically. But now I need to update the implementation of a form within our application which has many inputs. I want to create a dijit/Dialog for the specific DIV, and hope its div elements will be this dialog's elements. How is it possible?

Comment: to get form or elements in dialog you may try this
create a separate html file with all your input fields or form
then call this html file as 
new dijit.Dialog(
    {
        title:"Dialog Title",
        href:path of html file
    }
);

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. This code, will remove your `div` node from it's parent. `div` will be moved into `body` tag.

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");

var myDialog=new dijit.Dialog(
    {
        title:"Dialog Title",
        content:dojo.byId("divNodeID")
    }
);

myDialog.show();
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you surround your  with the HTML that will create a Dialog, it should work.

For example, if your code is:

```
<form>
   ... some HTML ...
</form>
```

then consider coding:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" title="MyTitle">
   <form>
      ... some HTML ...
   </form>
</div>
```